# In Unix,cmd to search a file recursively and retrieve the file instead of just the path of the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In Unix, what is the single cmd that lets me search and locate a file recursively and then retrieve the file instead of just the path of the file?

Comment: When in doubt just add clarifications (e.g. "retrieving"=="copying") you make in comments to answers directly to your question (you can edit it).  That way your question is much more likely to be answered [correctly].  Oh, and when you are satisfied with an answer, please accept it officially by clicking on the check mark. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat `find /wherever/you/want/to/start/from -name name_of_file`
```

Note those quotes are backquotes (`).

Comment: use $() instead of backticks as they are deprecated

Comment: @SiegeX: Good point, but OTOH backticks are supported by more shells (e.g. `csh`).

Comment: i m getting just the path of the file like this, but i want to copy that particular file onto a separate dir after finding!

Comment: @abhijthln: The command above will show the contents of the file(s).  I think you need to be much clearer about what you want.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : i want to search for a file, once its found, i want to copy the file itself onto another location. The search and the copying must be recursive.

Comment: @abhijthln: Much clearer!  (And completely different from what I thought you wanted.)  Edit your original question so it says that.

Comment: @abhijthln: Well I'm confused why you marked my answer as "correct" since it doesn't answer the question you actually want to ask...?  Maybe you meant to mark Aif's answer correct instead?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by retrieve?

You can simply use -exec argument to find.

```
$ find /path/to/search -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \;
$ find /path/to/search -type f -name 'pattern' -exec cp {} /path/to/new \;
```

The second one should work.

Comment: @asif:i m getting just the path of the file like this, but i want to copy that particular file onto a separate dir after finding!

Comment: @abhijithln edited. you should read some tuts about find, this is really powerful.

Comment: @asif:its for some appln in office, i don work on unix, i just went thru the basics of unix for this appln! thanks a lot! but, i don want to move that file, i wat it to be copied

Comment: @abhijithln: edited. I've replace the "mv" command by "cp". This is "aif" btw :)